# Multi Block Production

Tags: nodeos, block-producer

I want to create 4 Block Producers. I am following [this](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/local-multi-node-testnet)
tutorial and giving the same genesis for every node. I am only able to run two block producers. Is there any way to solve this?